# Create separate strategy alerts for long and short entries

Tags: pine-script

I need to create separate alert() function calls when my strategy goes long and short.

So eg pseudo code:

```
if strategy_goes_long
    alert(....)

if strategy_goes_short
   alert(...)
```

To be clear, I don't want to create an alert when the condition for the entry is true, bu rather when an actual entry in a given direction is taken by the strategy. This is because I want to use the strategy's built-in pyramiding settings to control when an entry is taken, so my alerts should only fire when an entry is taken.

So far I have tried:

```
if strategy.position_size > 0 and strategy.position_size[1] <= 0
    alert("went long")
   
if strategy.position_size < 0 and strategy.position_size[1] >= 0
    alert("went short")
```

But this was firing every bar, rather than only on the bars that an entry was made.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy example:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, alert_message="went long")

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short, alert_message="went short")
```

In the `Create Alert` dialog print `{{strategy.order.alert_message}}` and you will get alerts with messages you want:
[image: alerts]